# Find button class with selenium using the button text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

please I'm quite a selenium newbie and I would need help with the following.

I have this simple HTML code:

```
<button class="_5s5nM yZn2p  ">Log in</button> == $0
```

I need to find this element using the words "Log in".
I tried this code but I get an error message:

```
test_submit2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log in")
```

any idea of why it doesn't work?
Many thanks

Comment: does't loook like you've incuded any error message...

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code, this may work in your case:

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Log in')];
```

In your code the syntax seems to be incorrect, `linkText` will also work.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")):
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, i.e.

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Log in')];
```

However, one detail you forgot is that this is **By.XPath** and not By.linkText

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the application security, security testing services are used by developers to maintain dynamic nature of locators where the value class="_5s5nM yZn2p  " can be changed after some time.

So for your scenario the locator should be static like //button[text()= 'Log in'] and usage should be like driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()= 'Log in']")):